# Чем является слово "только" в данном предложении?

Tags: морфология, союзы, части-речи, частица

Небо было тёмное, только при вспышках молнии можно было рассмотреть тяжёлые тучи.
https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/k-kakoy-chasti-rechi-otnositsya-slovo-tolko.html
"Только" — это частица или союз? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Небо было тёмное, только при вспышках молнии можно было рассмотреть тяжёлые тучи.***

В данном предложении ТОЛЬКО является **частицей**.

Исходя из материала ссылки, приведенной в вопросе, ТОЛЬКО нельзя заменить ни на один союз. Между частями предложения нет подчинительной связи, оно  сложносочиненное, но противительные союзы ОДНАКО или НО сюда тоже не подходят. Можно подставить сочинительный союз И: *Небо было тёмное, **и** только при вспышках молнии...*

Чтобы проверить, что предложение бессоюзное, а ТОЛЬКО здесь — ограничительная частица, можно сделать перестановку:

*Небо было тёмное, рассмотреть тяжёлые тучи можно было **только при вспышках** молнии.*